# Simplification of differential equation when definition interval becomes small?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Assuming the following differential equation on the interval $0<x<c$ with a rational function $f(x,c)$

$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+f(x,c)\right)y(x,c)=0,$$

what kind of simplifications (if any) might occur for the solutions $y(x,c)$ when considering the case $0<c \ll 1$?

Also, when $c$ becomes small enough that the interval in questions consists only of two neighboring points, I assume that the differential equation above should reduce to a difference equation. Is this correct? And how exactly should that be managed?

EDIT:

If you would prefer an explicit example, please consider the ODE

$$\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\frac{c^2+x^2+x^4+x^{10}}{(1+x^2+x^{42})x^7}\right)y(x,c)=0$$

for the question above.

EDIT2:

Also, I think it is important to mention that at the left boundary $x=0$ we have Dirichlet boundary condition $y(0)=0$ and at the right boundary $x=c$ we have Neumann boundary condition $y'(c)=1$.

Comment: As stated: almost none what so ever. For all we know $f(x,c)$ can oscillate wildly as $c \to 0$. (You never defined what "well behaved" means.) (For example, let $f(x,c) = \frac{1}{c} \sin(x / c)$....)

Comment: Well behaved means a fraction of polynomials in x and c. The example $f(x,c)=\frac{1}{c}\sin(x/c)$ is blatantly non-well behaved under any definition of this word.

Comment: A function given by the ratio of two polynomials is called a 'rational function'; this is useful terminology.  'Well-behaved' is not typically used when you want to be *this* restrictive.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will remember and use this terminology next time. Also I will update the above question right now.

Comment: Well, since your function $f$ is smooth, for sufficiently small $c$, the solution to $y''(x) + f(0,0) y(x) = 0$ would be an approximate solution. A even better approximate solution would be $y''(x) + f(0,c) y(x) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It would be nice if you could elaborate on why these approximations are valid.

Comment: Also, what if $x=0$ is a pole of $f(x,c)$?